# What does "?:" mean in a Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Below is the Python regular expression. What does the `?:` mean in it?  What does the expression do overall?  How does it match a MAC address such as "`00:07:32:12:ac:de:ef`"?

```
re.compile(([\dA-Fa-f]{2}(?:[:-][\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5}), string)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It `(?:...)` means a set of non-capturing grouping parentheses.

Normally, when you write `(...)` in a regex, it 'captures' the matched material.  When you use the non-capturing version, it doesn't capture.

You can get at the various parts matched by the [regex](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) using the methods in the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re) package after the regex matches against a particular string.

---

> How does this regular expression match MAC address "00:07:32:12:ac:de:ef"?

That's a different question from what you initially asked.  However, the regex part is:

```
([\dA-Fa-f]{2}(?:[:-][\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5})
```

The outer most pair of parentheses are capturing parentheses; what they surround will be available when you use the regex against a string successfully.

The `[\dA-Fa-f]{2}` part matches a digit (`\d`) or the hexadecimal digits `A-Fa-f]`, in a pair `{2}`, followed by a non-capturing grouping where the matched material is a colon or dash (`:` or `-`), followed by another pair of hex digits, with the whole repeated exactly 5 times.

```
p = re.compile('([\dA-Fa-f]{2}(?:[:-][\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5})')
m = p.match("00:07:32:12:ac:de:ef")
if m:
    m.group(1)
```

The last line should print the string "00:07:32:12:ac:de" because that is the first set of 6 pairs of hex digits (out of the seven pairs in total in the string).  In fact, the outer grouping parentheses are redundant and if omitted, `m.group(0)` would work (it works even with them).  If you need to match 7 pairs, then you change the 5 into a 6.  If you need to reject them, then you'd put anchors into the regex:

```
p = re.compile('^([\dA-Fa-f]{2}(?:[:-][\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5})$')
```

The caret `^` matches the start of string; the dollar `$` matches the end of string.  With the 5, that would not match your sample string.  With 6 in place of 5, it would match your string.

Comment: Thank you but how does this regular expression matches MAC address "00:07:32:12:ac:de:ef"

Comment: @rawb ... it works and that too as one group re.findall prints it as a single group

Comment: It seems it is ok to remove `?:`, so what is the purpose of `(?:)`? Just for efficiency? Thanks! And the re pattern in re.compile() should be quoted by single(') or double(") quotes.

Comment: @Kai — you can just remove the `?:`, but then you have to renumber your captures — you've got an extra captured group.

Comment: @Kai: Thanks for noting the missing quotes — I've inserted them.

Answer (score 6):

Using `?:` as in `(?:...)` makes the group non-capturing during replace. During find it does'nt make any sense.

**Your RegEx means**

```
r"""
(                   # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\dA-Fa-f]          # Match a single character present in the list below
                          # A single digit 0..9
                          # A character in the range between “A” and “F”
                          # A character in the range between “a” and “f”
      {2}                 # Exactly 2 times
   (?:                 # Match the regular expression below
      [:-]                # Match a single character present in the list below
                             # The character “:”
                             # The character “-”
      [\dA-Fa-f]          # Match a single character present in the list below
                             # A single digit 0..9
                             # A character in the range between “A” and “F”
                             # A character in the range between “a” and “f”
         {2}                 # Exactly 2 times
   ){5}                # Exactly 5 times
)
"""
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but how does this regular expression matches MAC address "00:07:32:12:ac:de:ef"

Comment: ya it works.. thanks...but i want the answer as a single group

Comment: Try this ``(?is)\b(?:[A-F0-9]{2})(?::[A-F0-9]{2}){6}``.

Answer (score 2):

It does not change the search process. But it affects the retrieval of the group after the match has been found.

For example:
Text:
text = 'John Wick'

pattern to find:
regex = re.compile(r'John(?:\sWick)') # here we are looking for 'John' and also for a group (space + Wick). the ?: makes this group unretrievable.

When we print the match - nothing changes:
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='John Wick'>

But if you try to manually address the group with (?:) syntax:
res = regex.finditer(text)
for i in res:
print(i)
print(i.group(1)) # here we are trying to retrieve (?:\sWick) group

it gives us an error:

IndexError: no such group

Also, look:

Python docs:

(?:...)
A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

the link to the re page in docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

`(?:...)` means a non cature group. The group will not be captured.